# Question about proof of: showing $\delta(a+b)\leq\max\{\delta(a),\delta(b)\}$ for uniqueness of $q,r\in R$ in Euclidean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, euclidean-domain

*Background:*

**Definition:**  An integral domain $R$ is a Euclidean domain if there is a function $\delta$ from the nonzero elements of $R$ to the nonnegative integers with these properties;

*(i)*  If $a$ and $b$ are nonzero elements of $R$, then $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab)$.

*(ii)*  If $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0_R$, then there exist $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either $r=0_R$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(b)$.

**Exercise 1:** Let $R$ be a Euclidean ring with Euclidean norm $\delta$. Let $a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and let $q,r\in R$  such that $a=bq+r$ with $r=0$ or $\delta(r)<\delta(b)$. Prove that $r$ and $q$ are unique if and only if $\delta(a+b)\le\max\{\delta(a),\delta(b)\}$.

> Proof: Let $t,r$ be uniquely determined and suppose
>
> $\delta(a+b)> \text{max}\{\delta(a), \delta(b)\}$ for some $a,b$ (non zero) in $R$.
>
> Now $b=0\cdot(a+b)+b=1\cdot(a+b)-a$
>
> Also $\delta(-a)=\delta(a)<\delta(a+b)$
>
> and $\delta(b)<\delta(a+b)$
>
> Thus for $b, 1\in R$, there exists a $t=0$, $r=b$ or $t_1=1$, $r_1=-a$ such that $b=t$, $1+r$, $b=t_1\cdot 1 +r_1$ where $r\neq r_1$ (as $a+b\neq 0) t\neq t_1$, a contradiction to uniqueness.
>
> Hence $\delta(a+b)\leq \text{max}(\delta(a),\delta(b))$.

*Questions:*

In the above proof, where it says: "Now $b=0\cdot(a+b)+b=1\cdot(a+b)-a$ Also $\delta(-a)=\delta(a)<\delta(a+b)$", why is it necessary for the author to have $b=0\cdot(a+b)+b=1\cdot(a+b)-a$ and also where did $\delta(a)$ came from?   I understand that in the division algorithm from Definition above, that for $b=(a+b)$ and $r=-a$, and $r=b$, $q=0,1$ at this point of the proof.  I just don't understand the motivation behind its logic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note: a few weeks ago, OP asked a [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4831236/242) on the same exercise.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am asking a different question for the same exercsie.  I am asking for understanding the proof.  I reread the proof and there was something that I was confused about and I am asking for clarification from the community.

Comment: The proof shows  that if $a,b$ are both smaller than their sum then $\,-a,b\,$ are both possible remainders left on dividing $b$ by $a+b.\,$ Since $\,-a\neq b\,$ this shows that the division does not have a unique remainder.

Comment: @BillDubuque I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846740/question-about-a-proof-of-for-all-a-b-neq-0-in-mathbbz-p-and-ab-n) here.  It seem the technique:  $b=0\cdot(a+b)+b=1\cdot(a+b)-a$ is very common amongst these type of questions.  But why do we have to write $b$ in two different ways.  I am just not understanding the logic behind it.

Comment: @BillDubuque ah kk. Thank you for the clarification.  I did not know that is what the author is using.

Comment: @BillDubuque if it is not too much trouble, can I ask you to take a loook at the following [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846735/questiosn-about-two-proofs-for-showing-mathbbzi-i-is-finite-without-usin) [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846736/question-about-4n2-4n-1-in-showing-that-mathbbzi-i-is-finite), they are related but they are asking two different things.  It h as to do with quotient ring of gaussian integers.  Also I will delete my other post that is similar to this one.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: e.g. for  $\,2\div (2\!+\!1),\,$ we have  $\,2 = 0(2\!+\!1)\color{#0a0}{+2} = 1(2\!+\!1)\color{#c00}{-1}.\,$ Both $\,r = \color{#0a0}{+2},\,\color{#c00}{-1}$ satisfy $\,|r| < |2+1|\,$ so both $\,r\,$ are valid remainders, so remainders are not unique in $\Bbb Z$ with norm $\,\delta(n) = |n|.\ $ It's an obvious generalization familiar from [balanced remainder systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151636/242) in $\Bbb Z,\,$

Comment: e.g. we prefer $\,{-}1$ (vs. $10)$ for $\,10\bmod 11,\,$ when [casting out elevens](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242). That we have these $\rm\color{#c00}{two}$ possible smaller *magnitude* ($\delta$-size) choices is what destroys remainder $\rm\color{#c00}{uniqueness}$ in $\Bbb Z.\ \ $

Comment: @Seth: The statement in the exercise is not quite correct unless one adds that $\delta(a+b)\leq \max(\delta(a),\delta(b)$ of all $a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Mittens ah kk thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Seth: Here is a [page](https://planetmath.org/uniquenessofdivisionalgorithmineuclideandomain) that might be of interest

Comment: @Mittens ah kk thank you for the référence.

Comment: @Mittens can I trouble you with something very quick.  Do you know in which Euclidean domain where uniqueness of $q,r$ or $\delta(a+b)\leq\max\{\delta(a),\delta(b)\}$ can be satisfied.  I try a lot of popular examples from textbooks, but I am not haveing any sucess for the later condition and hence uniqueness of $q,r$ would fail. I am wondering if the exercise is only valid over polynomial rings or say Gaussian integers.  I don't know much about Algebraic number theory at the moment.

Comment: @Seth: I think in the ring of polynomials with $\delta(f)=\operatorname{deg}(f)$ of $f\neq0$. The condition you described in your posting is satisfied.

Comment: @Mittens so it is only with univariate polynomial rings?  But it won't work for multivariate polynomial rings?